# Highcharts Legend issue: I Wanted to make Legend 100% width and text center align it works fine in crome but it is not aligned center in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, legend, angular2-highcharts

try https://jsfiddle.net/74cgu6pm/7 on both crome and firefox you will get to know the issue.`legend: { width:'100%' },`

Comment: why not remove this propertirs from legend? By default it'll be centered. It should be a bug when use firefox

Comment: Actually, it is centered by default. Can you see any difference? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gauk938v/

Comment: Actually because of some reason, I wanted it to the full with by default it is half of the width.so I wanted to with width:100%

Comment: May I ask why do you need a full width of the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full width and center the legends, you can use custom legends with HTML & CSS and use CSS properties to style them

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
```

Otherwise use **itemDistance** property of Highcharts

```
legend: {
        itemDistance: 100
    },
```